# State Change Causing Sidebar Reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building an online store. When you click the checkout button, a sidebar slides into view showing the list of items in your cart. Inside of the cart is its list of items. You can change the quantity by toggling the up/down arrows in a `Form.Control` element provided by Bootstrap-React.

The way my code works is that when you toggle the up/down arrows to add or decrease the product quantity the state changes in the parent regarding what's in your cart. This triggers the child cart sidebar to close then reopen. I do not want this to happen! The sidebar should remain open.

I've tried two things; one is to use event.preventDefault() to try and make it so the page isn't refreshed, but this hasn't worked.

The other thing is trying to use `shouldComponentUpdate` and checking for whether the item quantity was changed, then preventing the app from re-rendering. This is the code I was using:

```
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (
      nextState.cart &&
      nextState.cart.length > 0 &&
      this.state.cart.length > 0
    ) {
      console.log("Next state cart num= " + nextState.cart[0].num)
      console.log("curr state cart num= " + this.state.cart[0].num)
      if (nextState.cart[0].num != this.state.cart[0].num) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    return true;
  }
```

The problem is that my previous and future props are the same! Hence I can't write any code preventing re-rendering on item quantity change.

Can anyone provide some advice?

Answer (score 0):

If your component is re rendering but its props and state aren't changing at all then you could prevent this with either [React memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) if you're using a function or if you're using a class based component then extending [React.PureComponent](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) instead of React.Component.

Both ways will do a shallow prop and state comparison and decide whether it should re render or not based on the result of said comparison. If your next props and state are the same as before then a re render will not be triggered.

Here's a [codepen example](https://codepen.io/deafening_roar/pen/eYOeJyv?editors=1011) so you can decide which one to use.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        count: 0
    };

    handleClick = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState(prevState => ({ count: prevState.count + 1 }));
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <span>Click counter (triggers re render): {this.state.count}</span>
                <button style={{ marginLeft: "10px" }} onClick={this.handleClick}>
                    Click me to re render!
                </button>
                <SingleRenderClassComponent />
                <SingleRenderFunctionComponent />
                <AlwaysReRenderedClassComponent />
                <AlwaysReRenderedFunctionComponent />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class SingleRenderClassComponent extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        console.log("Rendered React.PureComponent");
        return <div>I'm a pure component!</div>;
    }
}

const SingleRenderFunctionComponent = React.memo(
    function SingleRenderFunctionComponent() {
        console.log("Rendered React.memo");
        return <div>I'm a memoized function!</div>;
    }
);

class AlwaysReRenderedClassComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        console.log("Rendered React.Component");
        return <div>I'm a class!</div>;
    }
}

function AlwaysReRenderedFunctionComponent() {
    console.log("Rendered function component");
    return <div>I'm a function!</div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: I really appreciate the response- that seemed like a great answer when I first read it. Unfortunately, after changing my components to PureComponent's I didnt have any luck. Given your logic, im not sure why it didnt work.